# Como usar distinct para trazer um único resultado de cada item Dart/Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, distinct

Olá,
estou tentando trazer um unico resultado de cada titulo consumindo de uma API.
Como essa imagem mostra estou tendo titulos repetidos
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qual maneira que poderia fazer para corrigir, segue codigo até onde tentei com `distinct`

```dart
class AnimeBloc
    class AnimeBloc{

    final BehaviorSubject<List<Animes>> _listController   =BehaviorSubject<List<Animes>>.seeded([]);
    Sink<List<Animes>>  get listIn  => _listController.sink;
    Observable<List<Animes>> outList;

    Api api=  Api();


    AnimeBloc(){

      outList=_listController.stream.distinct().asyncMap((d)=>api.getAnimeName());
      print("teste $outList");
    }




    dispose(){
      _listController.close();
    }


    }
```

Aqui class da api

```dart
      Dio dio = Dio();

     Future<List<Animes>> getAnimes()async{
       Response response    =await dio.get(requestAnimes);
       if(response.statusCode==200){
         List<Animes> animes=
         (response.data as List).map((item)=> Animes.fromJson(item)).toList();
         return animes;
       }else {
         Exception("Erro na requisição");
       }
     }
```

e o minha tela com `StreamBuilder`

```dart
    StreamBuilder(
                        stream: bloc.outList,

                        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Animes>> snapshot){
                          if(!snapshot.hasData){return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);}
                          else if(snapshot.hasError){return Center(child: Text("Error "),);}
                          List<Animes> animes = snapshot.data;


                          return ListView.builder(
                              itemCount: animes.length,
                              itemBuilder:(context, index){
                                return
                                  GestureDetector(
                                    child: AnimeMainTile(
                                        snapshot.data[index]
                                    ),
                                    onTap: (){
                                     print( snapshot.data[index]);
                                    },
                                  );
                              }

                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como mencionado nas outras respostas, você pode implementar `equals` e `hash` em Dart, para poder usar o `Set()` diretamente com a classe `Animes`. Isso significa que você pode decidir exatamente como o programa irá julgar se dois objetos dessa classe são iguais ou não (por ex. todos seus campos precisam ser iguais, ou apenas alguns deles).

Como você se importa com a ordem, você pode utilizar o [LinkedHashSet](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-collection/LinkedHashSet-class.html) também. Esta é uma implementação do Set que mantém a ordem de inserção.

Porém, uma outra solução seria filtrar a lista com um `for`, utilizando apenas um campo como identificador, e adicionar em um `Set` apenas para verificação de existência:

Temos a lista original:

```
 List<Animes> animes = snapshot.data;
```

E criamos uma segunda lista que iremos popular com os itens distintos. Além dessa lista, criamos um set para verificar a existência:

```
List<Animes> animesFiltrados = [];
Set<String> animesInclusos = Set();
```

Então, percorremos os itens da lista original, verificando se já estão [inclusos](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/Set/contains.html) no Set. Se um item não estiver, incluímos tanto na lista nova, quanto no set. Se já estiver, não fazemos nada:

```
for (Animes anime in animes){
    if (!animesInclusos.contains(anime.nome)){
        animesInclusos.add(anime.nome)
        animesFiltrados.add(anime)
    }
}
```

Você não incluiu sua classe na pergunta, mas presumo que ela tenha um campo string do tipo Nome, por exemplo.

Não se esqueça de se basear na nova lista gerada quando for desenhar a tela:

```
return ListView.builder(
                              itemCount: animesFiltrados.length,
                              itemBuilder:(context, index){
                                return
                                  GestureDetector(
                                    child: AnimeMainTile(
                                        animesFiltrados[index]
                                    ),
                                    onTap: (){
                                     print(animesFiltrados[index]);
                                    },
                                  );
                              }

                          );
```

Tenha em mente que essa minha sugestão só funciona se não existirem dois itens diferentes porém com mesmo valor no campo "Nome" (por exemplo, um filme antigo e a refilmagem tem o mesmo nome, com datas de lançamento diferentes). Nesse caso você precisaria usar outra combinação de campos ou então implementar o Equals e Hash.

Vale lembrar também que essa solução percorre a lista inteira, o que pode trazer problemas se você traz essas informações de forma paginada ou se a lista é muito grande.

Answer (score 0):

Consegues exatamente o que procuras se usares um `Set` em vez de uma `List`.

O `Set` não te deixa ter objetos duplicados, uma `List` deixa;
A `List` é uma lista ordenada de objectos, já o `Set` não te garante que mantem a mesma ordem;

Basta usares o método `.toSet()` a partir de uma `List` (ou `.toList()` se tiveres um `Set`)

Ou então, filtras a tua `List`.

Comment: Eu não lembro se o `Set` mantém a ordem de inserção (o que poderia ser algo importante na exibição desse app, não ficou claro para mim), mas acho que não

Comment: Ah, precisa também implementar o `equals` e o `hashCode` na classe `Anime` para garantir o funcionamento do `Set`

Comment: Exato, é necessário implementar o equal e hash, é com base numa hash que os sets guardam os objetos.
O `Set` não te garante a ordem, significa que se a ordem ficar a mesma ótimo senão então terás de ordenar.